# Upload file with emoji as part of name using selenium python running in grid (linux platform)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, selenium-grid

I'm trying to upload a file named "űűőőóö.png" using selenium webdriver. The issue is that this is working fine with `send_keys` but when I ran with docker container with linux platform, the file name is getting converted to `?????.png`

Comment: Check that the locale in the docker container supports UTF-8.